# Functional equations elementary

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that 
$f(0)=1$ and $f(x)-f(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{3x^2}{4}+x$. Find $f(3)$.
How to proceed please help?

Comment: Please use  [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your question.  Also, share us your own thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(3)=f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{3}{4}\cdot3^2+3=f\left(\frac{3}{2^2}\right)+\frac{3}{4}\cdot3^2+3+\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{2}=...$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}f\left(\frac{3}{2^n}\right)+\frac{3}{4}\left(3^2+\frac{3^2}{2^2}+\frac{3^2}{2^4}...\right)+3\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...\right)=$$
$$=1+\frac{27}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{3}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=16$$

Comment: Some additional details wouldn't hurt. Can you explain how you arrive at your formula for $f(3)$?

Comment: $f(3)=f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\frac{3}{4}\cdot3^2+3=f\left(\frac{3}{2^2}\right)+\frac{3}{4}\cdot3^2+3+\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{2}=...$

Comment: Perhaps you could edit that into your answer?

Comment: I thought that it's obvious, but if you say... I fixed. Is it good now?

Comment: I agree that it's not super hard, but it took me a moment to see where you were going at first. I think it's better now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. Then we have $f(\frac{x}{2}) = \frac{ax^2}{4}+\frac{bx}{2}+c$. So
$$f(x)-f\bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg) = \frac{3ax^2}{4}+\frac{bx}{2} = \frac{3x^2}{4}+x \implies a = 1,\ b = 2$$
Using the initial condition, we have 
$$1 = f(0) = c \implies c = 1$$
Therefore, we have $f(x) = x^2+2x+1$ and $f(3) = 16$.

Comment: What happens when $f$ is not a polynomial? Or $f$ is a polynomial with another degree?

Comment: Then $f(x) = x^2+2x+1$ would be one of the functions that satisfies the given conditions for this case, instead of a general solution. To be honest, until I see your answer, I wasn't sure how to proceed in a situation like you said. Now I learned it :)